# Unity URP Error: Reduced additional punctual light shadows resolution

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, urp

I just downloaded Unity version 2021.3.0f1, and now I'm getting this error in the console:

> Unity URP Error: Reduced additional punctual light shadows resolution

I can still go into play mode but it makes the console annoying to work with.

[Console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E596F.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can still enter playmode, because the messages are "debug logs" not error messages.
Set the resolution of your point-lights to low.
Decrease your count of (runtime) point lights.
Increase shadow atlas size.

Answer (score 0):

The DIY answer is to comment out the line of code (just double click the warning message), then set that file to "Read Only" so the Unity package can't revert your changes.

Comment: well yeah i think thats a good option until unity decides to fix that. apparently the new version includes better lighting

Answer (score 0):

increases 'shadow atlas' in URP profile.
in my case,
[image: shadow atlas]